# Is it necessary to cast to float to access basic math functions in Rust?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1i32;
    let b = 2i32;

    let smallest = (a as f64).min((b as f64)) as i32;
    println!("{}", smallest);
}
```

Is all the casting to and from floats really necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  As a [quick search of the API reference reveals](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=min), you can just use `std::cmp::min`:

```
use std::cmp::min;

fn main() {
    let a = 1i32;
    let b = 2i32;

    let smallest = min(a, b);
    println!("{}", smallest);
}
```

`min` being declared specially on `f32` and `f64` is because floating point types do not implement `Ord`. Due to the presence of NaN, they only have partial ordering (`PartialOrd`) whilst `std::cmp::min` requires a total ordering (`Ord`).

Comment: It is explicitly separate for floats because they have NaN, and [the usual minimum](http://man.cx/fmin) handles them specially.

Comment: Derp, yes, I completely forgot about NaN.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the API reference search.  I'm writing my first rust program, and Google and Dash were not getting the results I needed.

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is [`::std::cmp::min`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.min.html), which works on any type that implements [`Ord`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html):

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1i32;
    let b = 2i32;

    let smallest = ::std::cmp::min(a, b);
    println!("{}", smallest);
}
```

You were using the min method from [`f64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.min) (an equivalent exists for `f32`).